# MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager seems not reusing conenction

Tags: java, servlets, httpclient

I use a `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` to manage http connections to a backend inside a servlet. The strange thing is that when I perform request with low rate (for example I interact in the front end via browser and I'm the only user) the connection inside the servlet takes 500ms to interact with the backend, but if I run a client that invoke with high rate the servlet method that use the `HttpClient` and I interact with browser, connections with backend are performed in 70ms!
It seems that when there is an high usage of connections they are maintained "alive" and reused.
Here the code:

```
    HttpConnectionManagerParams params = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();

    Integer socketTimeout =1000;
    params.setSoTimeout(socketTimeout);

    Integer connTimeout =1000;
    params.setConnectionTimeout(connTimeout);

    Integer httpClientThread =20;
    params.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(httpClientThread);

    params.setMaxTotalConnections(20);

    connman = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    //connman = new SimpleHttpConnectionManager();

    connman.setParams(params);
    connman.closeIdleConnections(10000);

    client = new HttpClient();
    client.setHttpConnectionManager(connman);
```

Comment: What is the question/problem please ?

Comment: The problem is related to "no connection reuse" when connection rate is low. There is a way to set timeout before a connection is closed in the pool? I want understand why when the system is heavy loaded the connection with the backend take 50-70ms instead of 500ms.

Comment: I've created a unit test that perform requests in sequence to the servlet that uses HttpClient with MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager. If the timeout between requests is 1 sec the HttpClient perform request in 400ms, but if the timeout between requests is 100ms HttpClient perform requests in 40ms. It seems that ConenctionManager has a very shot timeout before destroy the connection.